# Intent within same Activity - Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, double, achartengine

I have this Java code in a file which is a mix and match of two files. The original existing code + code for graphing random data. (Thanks to Dan and keshav for helping to get that working).

The graph displays on the app plotting random data. I would like to change the random data to my data. I have external accelerometer values as doubles further back in the app, and would like to use these values for the graph.

Code where doubles are now, being written to file:

```
@Override
public void onDataRecieved(TiSensor<?> sensor, String text) {
    if (sensor instanceof TiAccelerometerSensor) {

        final TiAccelerometerSensor accSensor = (TiAccelerometerSensor) sensor;
        float[] values = accSensor.getData();
        renderer.setRotation(values);

        viewText.setText(text);

        /**
         * The code here, when button clicked, adds the contents of the
         * edittext to the same file as x, y, and z
         */
        Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baddNametoFile);
        confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    EditText bodyText;
                    bodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ETName);
                    // bodyText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
                    // CAPS LOCK
                    String name = bodyText.getText().toString();
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                            new FileWriter(
                                    "/sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                                    true)));
                    out.println("<hr><br><br><br><h2 style=padding-left:20px;>"
                            + name + "'s Data below" + "</h2><br>");
                    out.flush();
                    // new arraylist
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not write file " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

        });

        /**
         * Code Below is for splitting the string (text) into three strings
         * (x,y,z) of just numbers and then printing them to a file
         */

         double doubx;
         double douby;
         double doubz;
        String accval = text;
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                            true)));
            String[] tempArr = accval.split("\\s+");
            String x1 = tempArr[0];
            String y1 = tempArr[1];
            String z1 = tempArr[2];

            String[] valxsplit = x1.split("=");
            String x = valxsplit[1];
            String[] valysplit = y1.split("=");
            String y = valysplit[1];
            String[] valzsplit = z1.split("=");
            String z = valzsplit[1];

            doubx = Double.parseDouble(x);
            douby = Double.parseDouble(y);
            doubz = Double.parseDouble(z);

            writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + "x is "
                    + doubx + "<br>" + "y is " + douby + "<br>"
                    + "Force is " + doubz + "</h3><br>");

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /** notification possibly */
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

//Then lots of code to do other things... then this in graph code

private int generateRandomNum() {
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    return randomInt;

}

protected class Update extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while (true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(700);
                x11 = x11 + 5;
                y11 = generateRandomNum();
                publishProgress(i);
                i++;

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        // return "COMPLETE!";
    }

    // -- gets called just before thread begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }// then more code... unrelated
```

I would like to change `y11`, from the code above, to `doubx`, from the code at top. When I try to just change `y11` to `doub x` in the code above I get an error saying `doubx cannot be resolved to a variable`.

I was wondering if intents could be used to pass the double down along the code,with the values they have, to where I want to use it again, however I know intents are usually used to pass data *between* activities, rather than *within*. Then again I'm new to Java and don't know if there is a way easier way to do this than I'm thinking. If anyone knows a way to please help.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: I added the code to define them at the top:

```
double doubx etc...
```

and it worked! Well with a little bit of changing in the code, which I've edited also. Thanks to Ivan and sush for their answers :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the doubx, douby, doubz to the member varialbes of outter class
like this:

```
class OuterClass {

     double doubx;
     double douby;
     double doubz;

     void method {
     String accval = text;
         try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("sdcard/YS Data/Accelerometer.html",
                        true)));

            .....

            doubx = Double.parseDouble(x);
            douby = Double.parseDouble(y);
            doubz = Double.parseDouble(z);

            writer.println("<h3 style=padding-left:20px;>" + "x is "
                  + doubx + "<br>" + "y is " + douby + "<br>"
                  + "Force is " + doubz + "</h3><br>");

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           /** notification possibly */
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

     protected class Update extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {

         .....

     }
}
```

Comment: Actually, placing this code in to define the doubles and then change a little bit and IT WORKED!! :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Define all your variables outside trycatch i mean make them as member variable. increase there scope. All are variables in localscope.

```
        double doubx = Double.parseDouble(x);
        double douby = Double.parseDouble(y);
        double doubz = Double.parseDouble(z);
```